# Последнее обновление PhpStorm 2020.1 SQL код

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm (лицензия) сам обновился...
Как только курсор попадает на строку с кодом SQL приложения подвисает а при попытке его выполнить и вовсе виснет! Если плагин отключить все работает. Как быть? База FireBird 3, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS